# Magento 1.9 - Shipping Calculator - Messages

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

On the view cart page I do not use the Show Method if Not Applicable option as this can be messy and irrelevant.  Therefore, if there are no available quotes Magento does not show any message by default.  What file would it be best to return an error message from to advise the customer there are no shipping methods available?

Answer (score 0):

In app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.html
Find the **endif** (approx line 120) for conditional statement if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): and add an **else** condition
Example:

```
    <?php else:?>
    <?php echo $this->__('There are no shipping methods available.<br/>Please use our contact form to obtain a shipping quote.'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```